# SQL multiple conditions CASE WHEN and or

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have joined two tables (tbl1 and tbl2). `AnimalNo` is present in both tables, but it is the primary key of tbl1 and can occur multiple times in tbl2 (if the `AnimalNo` is associated with multiple `ConditionID`)

`tbl1`

```
AnimalNo  |   KillDate
1         |   01/01/2019
2         |   01/01/2019
3         |   01/01/2019
4         |   01/01/2020
5         |   01/01/2020
```

`tbl2`

```
AnimalNo  |   ConditionID
1         |   1
1         |   2
2         |   1
3         |   1
3         |   2 
4         |   1
5         |   1
5         |   2
```

I would like a table where I get a count of the `AnimalID` which had each condition and the count of the `AnimalNo` which had both `ConditionID` 1 & 2, in the above example:

```
Year  |  N_killed   |  Type1   | Type2    | Both 
2019  |  3          | 3        | 2        |  2      
2020  |  2          | 2        | 1        |  1
```

I have this query which is successful at telling me the number of `AnimalNo` with each individual `ConditionID` but I would like to add the last column called `Both` which has a count of the `AnimalNo` which have both `ConditionID` 1 & 2

```sql
SELECT
  
  DATEPART(year, tbl1.KillDate) AS KillYear,
                COUNT(Distinct tbl1.AnimalNo) AS N_Killed,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl2.ConditionId =1 THEN 1 END) AS Type1,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl2.ConditionId =2 THEN 1 END) AS Type2
FROM            tbl1 LEFT JOIN
                         tbl2 ON tbl1.AnimalNo = tbl2.AnimalNo
WHERE YEAR(tbl1.KillDate) >=2012
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, KillDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, KillDate)
```

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Hi I have edited it there with some examples

Answer (score 1):

I think this is that you want

```
SELECT
  
  DATEPART(year, tbl1.KillDate) AS KillYear,
                COUNT(Distinct tbl1.AnimalNo) AS N_Killed,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl2.ConditionId =9 THEN 1 END) AS Type1a,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl2.ConditionId =75 THEN 1 END) AS Type1b,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl2.ConditionId =23 THEN 1 END) AS Type2a,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl2.ConditionId =81 THEN 1 END) AS Type2b,
                COUNT(CASE WHEN tbl2.ConditionId IN (9,75) OR tbl2.ConditionId IN (23,81) BothTypes
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN
     tbl2 ON tbl1.AnimalNo = tbl2.AnimalNo
WHERE YEAR(tbl1.KillDate) >=2012
GROUP BY DATEPART(year, KillDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year, KillDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @tbl1 table
(
AnimalNo int
,KillDate date
)

insert into @tbl1(AnimalNo, KillDate)
select 1, '2019-01-01' union
select 2, '2019-01-01' union
select 3, '2019-01-01' union
select 4, '2020-01-01' union
select 5, '2020-01-01'

declare @tbl2 table
(
AnimalNo int
,ConditionID int
)

insert into @tbl2(AnimalNo, ConditionID)
select 1,1 union
select 1,2 union
select 2,1 union
select 3,1 union
select 3,2 union
select 4,1 union
select 5,1 union
select 5,2


select
year(k.KillDate) as [Year]
,count(distinct k.AnimalNo) as N_Killed
,sum(c.Type1)
,sum(c.Type2)
,sum(case when c.Type1 = 1 and c.Type2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Both
from

@tbl1 k

JOIN
(
select 
c.AnimalNo
,max(case when c.ConditionID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Type1
,max(case when c.ConditionID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Type2
from
@tbl2 c
group by c.AnimalNo
) c
on k.AnimalNo = c.AnimalNo
group by year(k.KillDate)
```